# Annotation Processor in IntelliJ and Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, annotation-processing

**tl;dr**: I cannot configure IntelliJ to generate the java files in the same directory as gradle

I have a small project which uses the [immutables](https://immutables.github.io/) annotation processor.
It works as expected in the gradle command line build, but I cannot get IntelliJ to output the generated files to the same directory.

The full project is available on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/tmtron-immutables/encoding/tree/0.0.1)

**Gradle config**:
I use the folowing gradle plugins:

- [gradle-idea plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) which handles the idea configuration
- [gradle-apt-plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin) which provides the apt configuration and handles the compile-class path and idea config related to annotation processing (if also the idea plugin is applied)

relevant parts of the build-script ([link to the full listing](https://gitlab.com/tmtron-immutables/encoding/blob/0.0.1/build.gradle)):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
apply plugin: 'idea'

dependencies {
    def immutablesVersion = '2.3.9'
    compileOnly "org.immutables:value:$immutablesVersion:annotations"
    compileOnly "org.immutables:encode:$immutablesVersion"
    apt "org.immutables:value:$immutablesVersion"
}
```

when I start `./gradlew build` everything is as expected:
[image]

1. The source file `DataEncoding.java` is processed an the generated java-file `DataEncodingEnabled.java` ends up in
2. `/build/generated/source/apt/main` under the expected package `com.tmtron.immutables.data`
3. and the generated file is also compiled to a .class file

In IntelliJ I activate the annotation processing as suggested by the [gradle-apt-plugin docs](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin#intellij-idea):
[image]

Then I execute `./gradlew clean` to make sure, that the previous files are gone and then I click `Build` - `Build Project` in IntelliJ.
The annotation processor is executed, but the problem is that the generated java file ends up in the wrong location:
[image]

It is in:   /build/generated/source/apt/main/**build/generated/source/apt/main**/com.tmtron.immutables.data
the bold part is redundant.

What am I doing wrong and how can I set it up correctly, so that IntelliJ and gradle generate the files in the same directory?

Notes:

- I have of course already tried to just leave the "Production sources dir" in the IntelliJ annotation configuration empty, but his does not work: then it automatically uses "generated" and I also end up with a wrong path.
- IntelliJ version 2016.3.4

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPDATE 2.2019**
since Gradle 5.2 there is an easy way to do it - see [gavenkoa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173149/gavenkoa)s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54611475/1041641)

**UPDATE 5.2018**

The easiest way, I know of is to use the [apt-idea plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin#intellij-idea)

Just activate the plugin in the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'net.ltgt.apt-idea' version "0.15"
}
```

and then add the annotation processors to the `annotationProcessor` configuration:

```
final DAGGER_VER = '2.16'
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${DAGGER_VER}"
    annotationProcessor"com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${DAGGER_VER}"
}
```

Test-project on GitHub: [ex.dagger](https://github.com/tmtron/ex.dagger)
(using IntelliJ 2018.1.4, Gradle 4.7)

**ORIG ANSWER**

There's a simple workaround using the parent-dir which works fine in IntelliJ 2016.3.4

- Production sources directory: `../main`
- Test sources directory: `../test`

Now gradle and IntelliJ will generate the code to the same directories.

Fixed in [GitLab project V0.0.2](https://gitlab.com/tmtron-immutables/encoding/tree/0.0.2)

see also: [apt-gradle-plugin issue#35](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin/issues/35#issuecomment-282482795)

Answer (score 20):

Now https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin states:

> The goal of this plugin was to eventually no longer be needed, being superseded by built-in features. This is becoming a reality with **Gradle 5.2** and **IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1**.

So:

```
dependencies {
  compile("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.18")
  annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.18")

  compileOnly("com.google.auto.factory:auto-factory:1.0-beta6")
  annotationProcessor("com.google.auto.factory:auto-factory:1.0-beta6")

  compileOnly("org.immutables:value-annotations:2.7.1")
  annotationProcessor("org.immutables:value:2.7.1")
}
```

`compileOnly` is necessary if you use annotations, `compile` if you use classes, `annotationProcessor` introduced in **Gradle 4.6**.

To enable processing specific compile task:

```
compileJava {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor
}
```

To disable:

```
  compileTestJava {
      options.compilerArgs += '-proc:none'
  }
```

Comment: What about the IntelliJ configuration in 2019.1? Should I remove annotation processor?

Answer (score 13):

Hey there everyone I had the same issue and found a clean way of solving this issue.
I am using two libraries that require annotation processing (Lombok and MapStruct).

Also my IntelliJ is 2019.1 (update yours in case it's older) and Gradle 5.2.1.

First let's configure IntelliJ:

1. Disable Annotaion Processing in Settings, since we're going to delegate everything to Gradle:

[image]

2. Delegeate IDE actions to Gradle:

[image]

Last step is to configure your dependencies correctly in Gradle.

3. Dependencies section in Gradle:

[image]

Now you can execute the Build and Run from both command line and IDE.

Cheers!

Comment: Very helpful since it solved my JHipster project build problem.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.

Answer (score 1):

### 2019.2.x

- Disable annotation processor of intellij

[image: disableAnnotationProcessor]

- add, build directory in your gradle build.gradle file

[image: build.gradle]

- then run your gradle task to generate build file classes, example `gradle compileJava`

[image: runGradleTask]

- File -> project structure -> Modules -> Main Folder || remove exclude and add as source

[image: projectStructure]

And project should find all annotation and generated source file. Hope it helps.